# QFile::size() and size of buffer, that was deployed after reading the file are not the same

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Faced with a weird problem:
next code newer fails on debian linux:

```
    std::vector<char> rawData(sourceFile.size());
    auto bytesRead = sourceFile.read(rawData.data(), sourceFile.size());
    Q_ASSERT(bytesRead == sourceFile.size());
```

on windows 10 assertion failed

The `bytesRead`/`rawData.size()` are actually not equal to  `sourceFile.size()`. The file is actually stored in qrc resource file. Could someone please explain why does this happens on Windows platform.

Comment: Did you open the file in binary mode or text mode?  These types of programs that rely on exact file size should have the file opened in binary mode.  Please post how `sourceFile` is opened.

Comment: The file was opened in `QIODevice::Text`. Indeed this is a problem : `When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.`

Answer (score 0):

The file was opened in `QIODevice::Text`. This is the reason, why file size and buffer size differs : `When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.` : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum